# Getting the content of a recyclerView item in the Activity

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, onitemclicklistener

In my code I have a recyclerView that is being filled with data. On each item I have a radioButton and a couple of TextViews. How can I access the content of the clicked item's TextViews in my Activity?

This is my adapter:

```
public class SelectCategoryAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<SelectCategoryAdapter.MyViewHolder> {

    private Context mContext;
    private List<Category2> categoryList;
    private Category2 category;
    private RadioButton radioButton;
    int mCheckedPositon = -1;

    public class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        public TextView title, count, nameCategory;
        public RadioButton radioButton;

        public MyViewHolder(View view) {
            super(view);
            nameCategory = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.edittext_category);
            count = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.count);
            radioButton = (RadioButton) view.findViewById(R.id.radio1);
            //overflow = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.overflow);
        }
    }


    public SelectCategoryAdapter(Context mContext, List<Category2> categoryList) {
        this.mContext = mContext;
        this.categoryList = categoryList;
    }

    @Override
    public SelectCategoryAdapter.MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View itemView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
                .inflate(R.layout.adapter_select_category, parent, false);

        return new SelectCategoryAdapter.MyViewHolder(itemView);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(final SelectCategoryAdapter.MyViewHolder holder, final int position) {
        category = categoryList.get(position);
        holder.nameCategory.setText(category.getName());
        if (category.getTasks() < 10){
            holder.count.setText(" " + Integer.toString(category.getTasks()) + " ");
        } else {
            holder.count.setText(Integer.toString(category.getTasks()));
        }

        holder.radioButton.setOnCheckedChangeListener(null);
        holder.radioButton.setChecked(position == mCheckedPositon);
        holder.radioButton.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {

                mCheckedPositon = position;
                notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
        });

    }


    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return categoryList.size();
    }

}
```

I want to be able to see the content of "nameCategory" in my Activity. But only the one related to the item that the user just clicked.

Comment: Can you provide the code of your activity. Or just the snippet code from which you want to see the content of "nameCategory". Also, it will be better to provide the snippet code where you set the OnClickListener() on items.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
public class SelectCategoryAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<SelectCategoryAdapter.MyViewHolder> {

     MyCallBack myCallback;

     public interface MyCallBack{
         void listenerMethod(String textViewvalue);
     }

     public SelectCategoryAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<TaskComments> items, MyCallBack myCallBack) {
         this.context = context;
         this.items = items;
         this.myCallBack = myCallBack;
     }

     @Override
     public void onBindViewHolder(final SelectCategoryAdapter.MyViewHolder holder, final int position) {

         category = categoryList.get(position);
         holder.nameCategory.setText(category.getName());
         if (category.getTasks() < 10){
             holder.count.setText(" " + Integer.toString(category.getTasks()) + " ");
         } else {

          holder.count.setText(Integer.toString(category.getTasks()));
         }

         holder.radioButton.setOnCheckedChangeListener(null);
         holder.radioButton.setChecked(position == mCheckedPositon);
         holder.radioButton.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
             @Override
             public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
                 myCallBack.listenerMethod("Your data you want to transfer")
                 mCheckedPositon = position;
                 notifyDataSetChanged();
             }
         });

     }


}
```

And in your activity you can implement this interface to use it like this.

MyActivity.class

```
public class MyActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements 
   SelectCategoryAdapter. MyCallBack{


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        SelectCategoryAdapter adapter = new SelectCategoryAdapter(this, yourData, this);
    }




     public void listenerMethod(String textViewValue){
         Toast.makeText(this, "You have " + textViewValue +" Access in the activity now")

     }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but if I do that I get an error in the third parameter when calling the adapter in the activity. Because I'm passing this and it's expecting myCallBack. What should I do?

Comment: do you implement myCallBack inside activity ??

Comment: What do I have to do? Put the code of the interface inside of the activity and inside of the adapter?

Comment: as mentioned in my code you have to implement the interface and then you will override the listenerMethod inside the activity, thus when you use `this` in adapter constructor it will not give error. Refer MyActivity.class code.

Comment: I got this error: void com.construct.v2.adapters.categories.SelectCategoryAdapter$MyCallBack.listenerMethod(java.lang.String)' on a null object reference and category.getName() is being used a few lines above and is not empty there.

Comment: Even when I used a random string like myCallback.listenerMethod("Teste 2234"); I got the same error.

Comment: I managed to fix the null error. Apparently inside the this.myCallback = myCallBack; Android Studio was saying the i was trying to assign myCallback to itself so I changed to this.myCallback = myCallBack1; and it worked! Thank you very much!

Comment: You are creating a **NEW** OnCheckedChangeListener for EVERY element in the RecyclerView — this is bad practice. To see how to do it properly from Android Studio go to File > New > New Project and select **Master/Detail Flow** from the list of project templates.

Answer (score 1):

You can add an interface to communicate between your Activity and Adapter.

```
public interface SelectCategoryListener {
    void categorySelected(Category2 category);
}
```

You can then add a SelectCategoryListener to the constructor of your Adapter and set it as a global variable

```
public SelectCategoryAdapter(Context mContext, List<Category2> categoryList, 
                             SelectCategoryListener listener) {
    this.mContext = mContext;
    this.categoryList = categoryList;
    this.listener = listener
}
```

Now in your onBindViewHolder where you are setting your onClickListener you should be able to use listener to communicate between your Activity and Adapter.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Now, how do I call the adapter in the Activity and how do I access the data I am sending from the adapter to the activity?